# I have a question about the java jar package

Tags: java, spring-boot, intellij-idea, compiler-errors

My project uses gradle build, springboot project, can be run in IDEA, when I use IDEA to build the jar, I will report an error.I think it is a jar package that IDEA can't scan the logs.

The following is the location and information of the error：

```
log.warn(domainName + " id collection is empty");


Error:(293, 13) java: symbol not found
Symbol: variable log
Location: class run.halo.app.service.base.AbstractCrudService<DOMAIN,ID>
Error:(308, 13) java: symbol not found
Symbol: variable log
Location: class run.halo.app.service.base.AbstractCrudService<DOMAIN,ID>
Error:(53, 9) java: symbol not found
Symbol: variable log
Location: class run.halo.app.service.impl.ThemeSettingServiceImpl
```

Comment: If you're using Gradle why are you using IntelliJ to build the JAR file? Why not have Gradle build the JAR file? Or are you actually invoking Gradle through IntelliJ?

Comment: This is a project I used to learn. I am not very familiar with gradle, so at the moment I only use the tools of idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your class must be annotated with `@Slf4j` or `@Log4j2` or some other [lombok](https://projectlombok.org/) annotation.

You might not have the [lombok plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6317-lombok) installed, so the IDE is complaining that it can't find the `log` variable, which would look something like this when lombok injects it:

```
private static final Logger log = ...
```

Comment: You are right, I also found this problem, but the built jar has been invalid and corrupt.

Comment: @Bleibtreu The JAR couldn't have been built at all until you fixed this compiler error.

Comment: I have already opened the annotation of idai, and I have output the jar package normally, and the jar package is damaged or invalid.